# Elasticsearch joda time format error

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, format, logstash, jodatime

Using logstash I am trying to import date in json format in elasticsearch.
 I am using following mapping:

```
   "time_stamp": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dd-MMM-yy HH:mm:ss aa zzz"
          }
```

and trying to import `09-Dec-16 6:15:00 PM GMT` and get following error.

```
[2017-01-12T15:41:34,501][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Failed action. {
  : status=>400,
  : action=>[
    "index",
    {
      : _id=>nil,
      : _index=>"energy-2017.01.12",
      : _type=>"pam1",
      : _routing=>nil
    },
    2017-01-12T15: 41: 34.397Z%{
      host
    }%{
      message
    }
  ],
  : response=>{
    "index"=>{
      "_index"=>"energy-2017.01.12",
      "_type"=>"pam1",
      "_id"=>"AVmTV2GcrRd08tiPC0IZ",
      "status"=>400,
      "error"=>{
        "type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason"=>"failed to parse [time_stamp]",
        "caused_by"=>{
          "type"=>"illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason"=>"Invalid format: \"09-Dec-16 6:15:00 PM GMT\" is malformed at \"-Dec-16 6:15:00 PM GMT\""
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

any ideas why I am getting this error?

Comment: You should probably specifiy the locale as English. And why do you have in your input a combination of 24-hour-value (15) AND am/pm-marker???

Comment: it's not 24hrs, 15 is minutes i believe. I just tried setting locale to english i.e. "locale": "ENGLISH" but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Ah okay, minutes, your unformatted error message is not easy to read for me. Now I see 6:15:00 PM. But then you should really use the pattern part "h:mm:ss a" (small "h"). And again, the locale must be set to English anyway although I cannot tell you how to do it exactly in context of elasticsearch.

Comment: I think it's probably struggling at month part i.e. Dec and don't know how to parse that

Comment: In pure Java: `String input = "09-Dec-16 6:15:00 PM GMT";
  DateTimeFormatter dtf =
   DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yy h:mm:ss aa zzz").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
  DateTime dt = dtf.parseDateTime(input);` works for me.